# naughty button styles misbehaving

Tags: wpf, button, styles, isenabled

These two buttons; one is enabled and the one with the style is disabled. Can anyone figure out why?

```
<Button Command="{Binding ResolveHostsCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Grid.Column="0" Content="Resolve" />

<Button VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you set CanUserUpdateHosts to true, the Style.Setter cannot override the explicit value you provided in the Button declaration. See the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) page. Style setters in triggers are at #6, while the explicit value is #3.

You would need to reverse your logic, like so:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ResolveHostsCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Grid.Column="0" Content="Resolve" />
<Button  VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Or you could set the IsEnabled to false using a Setter of your Style, like so:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ResolveHostsCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Grid.Column="0" Content="Resolve" />
<Button  VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanUserUpdateHosts}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Inverting the logic is not necessary, you can turn the `IsEnable="False"` into a Setter of the style, which then will be overridden by the Trigger if it fires.

Comment: @H.B. Good point, I updated my answer to reflect that. I generally try to avoid "double setting" when I can, but you're right it doesn't need to be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

You have `IsEnabled` marked as false.

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"...>
```

Comment: Right, but I'm setting it to True in the style.  If the top one is true, then the bottom one is true.  It's clearly not honouring the DataTrigger.

Comment: You have explicitly set it though; it will override the inherited style.